# NodeJS ssl for subdomain

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a site, for example `test.com`, I need to make a copy of the same site with the address `subdomain.test.com` and change a couple of files on this subdomain for my purposes. The problem is that the categories of the site use NodeJS, and now running 9 NodeJS. Each server has registered SSL certificates of the following type (the settings are the same for everyone):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sslOptions = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem'),
    requestCert:        true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var https = require('https'),
    server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
```

I made a subdomain for example subdomain.test.com, but when I visit the site, the console swears at the following error: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

As I understand it, an error occurs because the certificate was issued for `test.com`, and I'm trying to use it additionally on `subdomain.test.com`. What can be done in this situation? Either in the NodeJS servers themselves when SSL certificates are connected, duplicate the settings by adding, for example, the number 1, or are there any other options?

Comment: So why not get a cert for `subdomain.test.com`?

Comment: i already get for `subdomain.test.com`, but in nodejs server use cert for `test.com` i don't know how to make multiple cert for `test.com` and `subdomain.test.com`, so that the site accepts this certificate